# Confused with spring MVC JSP page binding

Tags: java, jsp, data-binding, spring-mvc

I have not been able to solve my binding problem.

I have one class Person

```
Class Person {

Private fname;
private lname;
public Address address;
```

Now  one other class

```
class Address {

    private street;
    private suburb;
}
```

in controller i have

```
model.addAttribute("personAttribute", new Person());
```

IN jsp page i have

```
<form:form modelAttribute="personAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
<td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
```

Uptill this evrrythng is ok but when i add

```
<td><form:input path="street"/></td>
```

Then becomes the problem . i don't know how can i add Adress object with person.

i mean do i have to do

```
    model.addAttribute("personAttribute", new Person(new Address()));
    or

    model.addAttribute("addressAttribute", new Address());
or

td><form:input path="person.address.street"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to bind path like that :

```
<td><form:input path="address.street"/></td>
```

It's because you are in scope of `Person` object in binding.

Comment: i have Set<Address> in person object will that make any difference

Comment: @Pasha Yes it makes. I recommend to you [AutoPopulatingList](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/AutoPopulatingList.html) in this case. Then you have to bind address like `addresses[1], addresses[2]` ...

Comment: actually i am not retrieving , but i am inserting values. so like ur address.street (it worked) , how can now i write like Address[].street or what. is there any online example where list or set is binded in spring form

Comment: Read/write is managed by binding, so if you bind correctly your data object correctly, that when you POST it to server you have it filled in your method in input argument annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. Refer to [Spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is correct:

```
model.addAttribute("personAttribute", new Person());
```

This will initialize the Person with empty attributes, including an empty Address.

If you want to make sure that the address is not empty, you have to pass a person instance that contains a value. For example

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("John");
person.setLastName("Smith");

Address address = new Address();
address.setStreet("#10 Avenue");
address.setSuburb("Cook");

person.setAddress(address);
```

Normally you may want to populate the person object with a value retrieved from a database or data source.

Comment: Actually i am inserting value in database . so can u please explain what i have to write in jsp page like person.address.street is valid name there